# odoo 16 mail from crm.lead always reply-to catchall

Tags: email, crm, odoo-16

I configured an incoming and outgoing server.

under "ACTIONS TO PERFORM ON INCOMING MAILS" in incoming server

I choose crm.lead which works perfectly. all emails coming in generate a lead in pipeline.

so far so good. In the generated leads i see the mail and can answer this mail and the mail will be delivered to the receipient whose mail created this lead.

But when i answer to this mail which comes from the lead the mail will be delivered to catchall@mydomain. in the mails header i see the value fo reply-to is always catchall@mydomain.

How can i solve this issue, so that the reply-to value is the email of the receipient of the mail which generated the lead.

I tried to changed the reply-to value in the method message_new which i have overwritten. But this doesnt work.

What i finally try to realize is, that it should be possible to make a conversation out of the lead, with emails and replies.

Hope that someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, can you [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]? If not, it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I too am very frustrated with how Odoo handles e-mails. It's just not correct, but they have gone so far in the wrong direction they cant correct. Every other CRM/System out there allows you to login via google/yahoo etc and record incoming out going messages directly. Not odoo

Odoo utilizes a notification system of sorts. Because of this, the default reply is "catchall@yourcompany.odoo.com" this allows the odoo server to injest the message. Then based on the e-mail raw header data the odoo server finds the associated origination recordm it then looks at all of the followers of that record and sends another email copy+paste of the senders message --- excluding the original sender.

Totally confusing to everyone involved, no one can see who else is CC'd, if someone decides to CC a new member they are not actually there and no one knows who is seeing the message or not. Additionally from a mail/spam standpoint many sender domains prohibit this type of re-distribtuion....which cause deliverability issues to your final inbox as well as a mismatch often times in outgoing messages.